# Call function in img tag in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have this function and I pass it in `img` tag in HTML

```
check(imgNumber)


<script>
        var data = <%- JSON.stringify(@data) %>;
 function check(value) {
        var arrN = ["15","16","35","36","n15","n16","n35","n36","n37",];
        for (var i = 0; i < arrN.length; i++) {
            if (img === arrN[i]) {
             return "/icon_"+imgNumber+"_en.png";
            }
        }
        return "/icon_"+imgNumber+".png";

    }
        </script> 

        <div id="main">

        <img class="status-icon" src="check(<%= @data.imageEng %>)" width="26" height="auto" />
        </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

I got this error  http://localhost:3000/icon/check(3) 404 (Not Found)
and photo is not appearing. 
How can I solve this?

Comment: Are you using any server side scripting language?

Comment: ya i use express from server side i take number of photo

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> <img class="status-icon" src="check(<%= @data.imageEng %>)"
> ```

You can't do it like that; the src= tag is not evaluated. You have to do it differently (a library like jQuery might help too):

```
<img id="id12345" src="about:blank" eng="<%= @data.imageEng %>" />

...
<script>
    var img = document.getElementById('id12345');
    img.src = check(img.eng);
</script>
```

But actually, you could do it all server side with no Javascript at all. The changes are not made client side and the server should have all necessary data.

Comment: in server side i use express i cant use for loop in it